# Find the subgroups of the groups $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: group-theory

Q: Please find the subgroups of the groups $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$.

Is the answer:

$\{0\}, \{0,1,2,3,4\} \le \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

$\{0\}, \{0,5\}, \{0,2,4,6,8\}, \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \le \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm making two assumptions:

1) Is it safe to assume that addition is the implied operation?

2) Am I correct that the subgroup follows the modulus of the main group and doesn't set use its own subgroup modulus? Obviously $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} = \{0,1,2,3\}$ is a group modulus $4$, but that set is not closed modulus $5$.

Comment: Yes...yes, yes, yes... :-)  (note that  $5$ is prime, and note that $10 = 2\times 5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right on both counts, and your answers are correct. Can you see how to generalize them to say when $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Another good problem to try is to show that *every* subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ for some $k$. This is a bit harder though.